# I have seen many different ways to use CURL in PHP. Which is the "right" one?

Tags: php, curl

I have read that CURL is way too fast than File Get Contents and less memory consuming. So, I will go with CURL. I read some articles to find info about it and how to use it properly and efficiently. 
The problem is that I found many ways of using CURL, I posted 3 variations below.

My question is which one is the best to use?

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
  $content = curl_exec($ch);


     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     $cache = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);


 $ch = curl_init("");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Which solution works the fastest for you and returns the results you expect?  That's what it comes down to, what works for you.

Comment: This is like asking "I have to go somewhere. Do I walk, drive, or bike"? Well, depends on what you're doing, how far it is, and how much stuff you have to haul around.

Comment: @Crontab So is not a standard code procedure. Should I go with the working solution with less code lines? Is there any possibility of errors ?

Comment: No, there isn't a particular standard to how you use cURL.  "If it doesn't work, you're doing it wrong!" is pretty much the only thing that applies here.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what options you want.  Most of cURL's options will have some default, which will be set if you do not manually set an option.

For example: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` defaults to FALSE (so setting it to FALSE in your code would be redundant).

Passing a parameter to `curl_int` is just a shortcut for `CURLOPT_URL`.  The other options all depend on what you want to do.

Here is a list of all the cURL options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Pick the options you want, exclude those you don't.  There's no "right" way, just the way that works the way you want.

Comment: Someone Australian-upvoted you. :P . I don't see a problem with your answer, so I upvoted you for real to undo it.

Comment: @Deltik: That's it, I'm using the term "Australian-upvote" now.  Though this might not make much sense if you were actually in Australia; oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Its like asking,

> I have see many ways people code PHP, but which one is right?

There is no correct answer for such question, as everybody is going to have their own opinion about every way.

So, I suggest you read the PHP.net's manual on [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and choose the correct method based on your coding style, requirement and construct.

Answer (score 0):

1 is SSL (https:// or ftps://)

2 I think is a plain old ftp:// or http:// url

3 I am not sure what it is. looks like generic URL stuff without SSL.

did you check the notes in the example and read the documentation to see what exactly the functions do or the code does?  you can feed curl_init a URL string.

get the .chm documentation with notes. it will help a lot and speed up your research.

looks like you need to have to put in some code that does this:

```
<?php
function getfile($url) {
$result="";
$protocol=substr($url,0,strstr($url,":"))
if ("https"==$protocol || "ftps"==$protocol) {
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
   $content = curl_exec($ch);
} else {
   //it's http or ftp
   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close ($ch);
}
return $result;
}
?>
```